# Why is the function in the background not being called?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a program which will record the song title and artist of the currently playing song on the itunes app, but when I click the home button the app does not record the title or the artist anymore. The background function works because when I click the home button the test function works, but for some reason the getNowPlayingItem does not work. How do I fix this?

```
  var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    print("entered background")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()


    test()
}

func test(){
      print("Background function working")
        }

func getNowPlayingItem() {
    if  let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem  {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
        let artisttest = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
        if let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String{

            let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")
            let object = PFObject(className: "MasterSongs")

            //    print("Artist: " + artist)


            let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                    self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

                    // print(self.Parsearray)
                }


                if self.Parsearray.contains(title!){
                    print("already in db")
                }else{
                    objectPointer["title"] = title
                    objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    objectPointer["artist"] = artist
                    objectPointer.saveInBackground()


                }

            })




        }else{
            let object = PFObject(className: "MasterSongs")
            object.setObject(title!, forKey: "title")
            //object.setObject(artist!, forKey: "artist")
            object.saveInBackground()

            let objectPointer = PFObject(className: "Pointer")


            let query = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

                for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
                    self.Parsearray.append((objectIDs[i].valueForKey("title") as? String)!)

                    // print(self.Parsearray)
                }


                if self.Parsearray.contains(title!){
                    print("already in db")
                }else{
                    objectPointer["title"] = title
                    objectPointer["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    objectPointer["artist"] = "No artist found :("
                    objectPointer.saveInBackground()


                }

            })





        }


    }


}
```

Comment: your application stays alive only 30 seconds when it goes to background. You have to create a background task and that will help your app to keep working for 3 more minutes.

Comment: How would I do that, and can I have the app run in the background longer than 3 minutes?

Comment: it will drain too much battery that is the reason why it is not officially allowed by Apple unless you use a framework just like location services. (even when services like location services running, you can only let your app running when screen is not locked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this way you run the background task and let the stay alive 3 more minutes.
Start this only when the app goes to background.

`var backgroundTask:UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({ () -> Void in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask!)
            self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        })`

Comment: Where would I call my functions and put the `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()` method?

Comment: just leave it as it is and add the background code `applicationDidEnterBackground ` method . This piece of code lets the app to run 3 more minutes actively. And as soon as it is kept alive, other processes will continue. After 3 minutes, the background task will be invalid and the app will go to inactive mode.